# Объясните, пожалуйста, почему выводится только один элемент

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

to_write = {}
link = 'https://www.flashscore.ru/'

def get_shedule_data(link):
    try:
        browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        browser.get(link)
        time.sleep(15)
        root_div = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.sportName').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(root_div, 'lxml')
        all_events = soup.find_all('div', class_='event__match')
        for event in all_events:
            team1 = event.find('div', class_='event__participant--home').text
            team2 = event.find('div', class_='event__participant--away').text
            to_write['team1'] = team1
            to_write['team2'] = team2
        print(to_write)

    finally:

        browser.quit()

def main():
    get_shedule_data(link)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

На выходе следующее: 
{'team1': 'Маккаби Нетания (Изр)', 'team2': 'Бейтар Тель Авив (Изр)'}
Изначально предполагалось, что каждый полученный элемент в результате прохождения цикла будет записываться в словарь. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся.

Comment: Есть предположение, что я просто перезаписываю значение.

Comment: `to_write['team1'] = team1`, `to_write['team2'] = team2`

Comment: Думаю вы все переписываете друг на друга. Пробуйте менять ключ. to_write['team1' + event.id] или что там есть уникальное

Comment: Сделайте список, в который каждую итерацию добавляйте to_write и у вас получится список из нужных словарей. Или меняйте ключ каждую итерацию.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
to_write = {}
```

примените

```
from collections import defaultdict

to_write = defaultdict(list)
```

и затем вместо

```
        to_write['team1'] = team1
        to_write['team2'] = team2
```

примените

```
        to_write['team1'].append(team1)
        to_write['team2'].append(team2)
```

---

**Объяснение:**

Вы не хотите в цикле *менять* (переписывать) значения ключей, а *добавлять* их к списку.

При этом возникает проблема: Когда ключ ещё не существовал, его значение не определенно, потому невозможно добавлять к нему - нужно сначала создать пустой список как значение нового ключа.

**Преимущества `defaultdict`:**

1. Не надо контролировать, если ключ в словаре уже существует (чтобы при его отсутствии присвоить ему пустой список), всё делается автоматически.
2. Иначе работа с ним та же самая, как с обыкновенным словерем.

---

*Примечание:*

Когда вам `defaultdict` не нравится, вы можете то же самое достигнуть применением метода `.setdefault()` к обыкновенному словарю:

```
         to_write.setdefault('team1', []).append(team1)
         to_write.setdefault('team2', []).append(team2)
```